Why does the Nicene Creed not use the attribute ' consubstantial ' for the Holy Spirit?
Following are some excerpts from the Nicene Creed:

I believe in one Lord Jesus Christ, the Only Begotten Son of God, born of the Father before all ages. God from God, Light from Light, true God from true God, begotten, not made, consubstantial with the Father...
I believe in the Holy Spirit, the Lord, the giver of life, who proceeds from the Father and the Son, who with the Father and the Son is adored and glorified, who has spoken through the prophets.
(Source: United States Conference of Catholic Bishops)

Here, the Creed speaks of God the Son as consubstantial with the Father. But when it comes to describing the Holy Spirit, it does not use the attribute 'consubstantial'. What is the explanation for the same?
Inputs are welcome from any denomination that has adopted the Nicene Creed.

There are actually two questions here. Before we can address why the Creed says (or doesn't say) what it does (or doesn't), we need to know what Nicene Christians believe about the substance of the Holy Spirit.
Is the Holy Spirit of one substance with the Father?
The answer seems to be "yes". Consider:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cappadocian_Fathers
What does the Nicene Creed mean when it says that the Father and the Son are of the same substance?

The Athanasian Creed is somewhat more explicit, demanding that when we think of the Trinity, we "neither confound the Persons, nor divide the Essence". (Though often translated "essence", the original Latin is "neque substantiam separantes", where "substantia" is equated to the Nicene "ousia"... and, confusingly enough, is sometimes translated "substance" elsewhere within the Athanasian Creed itself). However...
Why doesn't (e.g.) the Nicene Creed clarify this?
Careful inspection of the above sources reveals that the debate over the consubstantiation of the Holy Spirit seems primarily associated with the Macedonian / Cappadocian split, which was roughly contemporaneous with the Council of Nicea. That is, at the time the Nicene Creed was being formulated, consubstantiation of the Holy Spirit was still being contested. Thus, one possibility is that the authors of the Nicene Creed chose not to make a stance on this particular issue.
However, another possibility is that it wasn't seen as crucial. While they certainly contain broad descriptions of the Christian Faith, the Creeds (in particular the later Nicene and Athanasian creeds) were formulated to address specific issues. It's also possible that the authors felt that consubstantiation of the Holy Spirit was an obvious conclusion when consubstantiation of the Son was established, and therefore felt it unnecessary to belabor the point.
Without explicit writings from the authors themselves, we really can't be certain why the Nicene Creed doesn't specifically mention consubstantiation of the Holy Spirit.

The Orthodox Church: uses the unmodified Nicene Creed created by the eucumenical council of the same name. (No "and the son" // filioque clause)

And in the Holy Spirit, Lord and Giver of Life, who proceeds from the Father, who together with the Father and the Son is worshipped and glorified, who spoke by the prophets . . .

God the Father is the eternal origin and source of the Spirit, just as it is the source of the Son. What is said of 2 persons is true to the 3rd as well, so when the Father and Son are consubstantial... the Holy spirit is as well. Likewise, if the Holy Spirit proceeded from the Father and Son, then the Holy spirit would would also proceeds from Himself. (Which is one of the reasons why we don't have that in the Nicene Creed)

This is called Triadology: the notion that for any given trait, it must be either common to all Persons of the Trinity or unique to one of them. Thus, Fatherhood is unique to the Father, while begottenness is unique to the Son, and procession unique to the Spirit. Godhood, however, is common to all, as is eternality, uncreatedness, and so forth. -Mr. Bultitude on another question

Is the Holy Spirit of one substance with the Father? Yes
Why doesn't the Nicene Creed say it again? It is not necessary, they are all God.

